# Why "cfg\pirates-wp8.cfg" doesn't match regex ".*pirates\\-wp8\\.cfg"

Tags: java, regex

I am using java and trying to filter files using

```
filename.matches(".*pirates\\-wp8\\.cfg");
```

Why "cfg\pirates-wp8.cfg" doesn't not match regexp ".*pirates\-wp8\.cfg"

I also tryed this:

```
filename.matches(".*pirates-wp8\\.cfg");
```

doesn't work.

Comment: `"cfg\\pirates-wp8.cfg".matches(".*pirates\\-wp8\\.cfg")` returns `true`...

Comment: 2 slashes works when you type ".*pirates\\-wp8\\.cfg" as a string parameter for the "matches" method, but I am receiving this string from remote source and when I see its value in debug and it shows 2 slashes it doesn't work. When I make 1 slash in the variable, it works.

Comment: now I see I described my problem not very clear, because this is a huge project, and I simplified teh code wrongly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the mistake was in double slashes. 
    ".*pirates\-wp8\.cfg"
- this regex works

Comment: The double backslashes are needed. You're regex as is will also match `anything\pirates-wp8Xcfg` for example.

Comment: @TheLostMind "\\\\" will be handled as "\\" which will match one single backslash, while the OP does not need to match a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm rather new to Java, but may be this helps.
I made a [tiny example](http://ideone.com/GGNVeV) for you, and seems to work.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        String filename = "cfg\\pirates-wp8.cfg";
        boolean b = filename.matches(".*pirates-wp8\\.cfg");
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 slashes works when you type ".*pirates\\-wp8\\.cfg" as a string parameter for the "matches" method, but I am receiving this string from remote source and when I see its value in debug and it shows 2 slashes it doesn't work. When I make 1 slash in the variable, it works.

Answer (score 0):

The start of your regex string meeds to be **.*?** because **.*** on its own is greedy and eats up the whole string being matched, then can't match the rest of the regex.  And just by the way, the hyphen doesn't need to be escaped, though it's not actually wrong to do so. So your line needs to be:

```
filename.matches(".*?pirates-wp8\\.cfg");
```

Comment: no, in my case I need .* because I need greedy beginnning and find everything which ends with "pirates-wp8.cfg", any paths